# Normalize space for list items and extract as array using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, parsel

I am looking for an efficient way to extract list items as an array. They need to be stripped of any extra spaces. Currently I am doing this:

```
actions = []
actions_list = sel.xpath('//div[label="Actions Taken"]/article/div/ul')
action_items = actions_list.xpath('li')
for a in action_items:
    actions.append(a.xpath('normalize-space(text())')[0].extract())
```

The actions array gets stored in my database. Is there a more efficient way of doing this in Scrapy?

Comment: can you share part of html structure? this looks that can be done with only xpath

Comment: <div class="ie7and8article">
    
                            <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        Information Exchanged
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        Directed to Comply
                                    </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

Comment: What you say you want is better achieved with the .strip() string method. normalize-whitespace() also replaces sequences of whitespace with a single space.

Answer (score 2):

The following xpath should do the same you are doing:

```
sel.xpath('normalize-space(//div[label="Actions Taken"]/article/div/ul/li/text()[0])').extract()
```

but it depends on the page